Send automated email when layer is updated in the field using Field Maps
I have an ArcGIS Online Map and Field Map that my team uses to collect field data. I want to use a webhook to send me an email automatically every time a layer gets updated. I am using this documentation:
Automate email notifications for field updates
The problem I am running into is that it seems like I have to make a new "scenario" for each layer on the map.
Is there a way I can make one scenario that will run through all of the layers of my map?
